# Проблема с созданием apk

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать, с чем может быть связана проблема ошибки при создании `apk`-файла приложения? Система пишет:

> Generate signed APK: Errors while building apk, see messages tool window for list of errors.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>
> Failed to read key Programs1 from store "C:\Users\Desktop\keys1.jks": Cannot recover key

Как можно устранить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Скорей всего Вы потеряли, или переместили в другое место, ключ, который использовали при создании apk. Надо создать новый ключ, но обновить apk в гугл маркете Вы не сможете. Придется удалять приложение и заливать заново с новым ключем

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего просто вводите неверный пароль.
Стоить помнить что если вы забудете пароль то восстановить вы его не сможете.
Если создадите новый ключ то придется менять имя пакета. 
Старое приложение обновить уже не сможете.